# XPath select node in Xaml

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, xpath

I would like to match a node within a xaml-file and my file looks like this:

#### Some Xaml (xml-like) input:

```
<SomeNode> <!-- this is root btw -->
    <!-- [...] -->
    <SomeNode.AnyProperty>
        <!-- [...] -->
    </SomeNode.AnyProperty>
    <!-- [...] -->
</SomeNode>
```

and I want to math just the section '`SomeNode.AnyProperty`'.
Afterwards I want to replace this found node by a generated one.

Any suggestions for a working `XPath` expression? I tried common expression like those I would apply on a usual xml-file like: "SomeNode.AnyProperty". But for sure, this did not worked.

### Working Solution:

Thanks for all support. The problem was not the `XPath` expression itselft. Furthermore it was the namespace declaration of my xaml input file. To avoid this namespace problems i used a modified version of @malkam solution.

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("someFile.xaml");
  //Get required element
  XElement nodeToReplace = doc.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "SomeNode.AnyProperty").FirstOrDefault() as XElement;
  //replace it with requried element
  nodeToReplace.ReplaceWith(someOtherNodeIGeneratedEarlier);
  doc.Save("someFile_editet.xaml");
```

Comment: It works for me. How exactly are trying to use that XPath?

Comment: I tried to use it within `XmlDocument.SelectNode(XPath xpath)`. I think the Problem wasnt the XPath itself, furthermore the namespace declaration of my xaml was the evil guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
//Load xml in XElement
string xml="xml";
XElement xmlTree=XElement.Parse(xml);
//Get required element
XElement child = xmlTree.Element("SomeNode.AnyProperty");
//replace it with requried element
child.ReplaceWith(
    new XElement("NewChild", "new content")
);
```

See below links for more details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb302711.aspx

Comment: The question specifically asks about XPath.

Comment: The way using an `XElement` istead of `XmlDocument` and then `XmlDocument.SelectNode(XPath xpath)` solved my problem actualy. I had to use an workaround to avoid namespace problems, but it finaly does its job! I'll add the solution to the question above.